# asp.net mvc ajax call not calling controller after publishing on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, request

this is for the first time I am having a problem like this,

my code is running smoothly on my localhost, but i am getting the error of bad request after uploading the same code on my server,

the following is the error I am getting,

> http://URL/Controller/Method 400 (Bad Request)

here is my code

```
Controller:

    [Interceptors.AccountFilter]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult method(string city, int bookmark)

Javascript:
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/controller/method",
            data: {
                city: city,
                bookmark: bookmarks
            },
        })
```

what can be the possible issue that i am getting,

**PS:**

the code is running on localhost properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking off the first '/' so your url will become: "controller/method".

I would also put a piece of code in the first line of the method to check that the address is correct and is triggering.

You can also try temporarily commenting out the two lines below. They aren't needed for testing and looking at the first attribute would probably stop your request.

```
[Interceptors.AccountFilter]
[HttpGet]
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code from `url: "/controller/method"` to `url:'@Url.Action("method","controller")'`

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment) Please change the "customErrors" tag on web.config so you can see the error details

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
```